# ¿En qué lugares se usa "ves" como imperativo de "ir"?

Tags: verbos, españa, pronunciación, imperativo

Por experiencia propia sé que en algunos sitios de España es común decir "ves" en lugar de "ve" como imperativo del verbo *ir*. Los casos con los que me he encontrado son:

- Cataluña. Ignoro el motivo, pero he visto "ves" escrito hasta en traducciones realizadas allí (como pasa con los mangas publicados por la editorial Planeta, que suelen tener traducciones no demasiado revisadas). Imagino que puede ser por influencia del mismo tiempo expresado en catalán.
- Castilla-La mancha. Me contaron que es común decir "ves" para enfatizar, incluso en expresiones como "veste a la mierda" (literalmente, ese fue el ejemplo que me dio una chica de Albacete).

Esta expresión se encuentra incluso en textos del CORDE:

> *—Ves a casa del Sr. Castro y Serrano a ver cómo está, y si no le ha pasado nada, dí al cocinero que me ponga para almorzar de las setas de ayer.*
>
> Ángel Muro, "El Practicón. Tratado completo de cocina", 1891-1894 (España).

Y en expresiones orales recogidas por el CREA, marcadas como de formalidad baja:

> *Tú ves a la farmacia y pide morfina.*

Lo que me gustaría preguntar es: ¿en qué otros lugares de España es común oír a la gente pronunciando "ves" en lugar de "ve"? ¿Qué motivos hay en cada sitio para pronunciarlo así?

Nota: aunque la pregunta está enfocada a España, si en algún país de Hispanoamérica también sucede, se puede añadir igualmente a la respuesta (aunque creo que allí se usa más "andá").

Comment: "Andá" no se diría en México.  Ni tampoco "anda" en este contexto.

Comment: tu ves y él ve.

Answer (score 5):

#### Regiones y motivos en las que se usa "ves" en lugar de "ve" como imperativo del verbo "ir":

- España:

  - Castilla-La Mancha (como forma de enfatizar).
  - Cataluña, Comunidad Valenciana, Islas Baleares, Región de Murcia (posiblemente influenciadas por el catalán *vés*).
- México:

  - Orizaba (Veracruz)

Answer (score 2):

Lo he escuchado mucho mi natal estado de Veracruz, en México: "Ves a decirle", "Ves rápido a la tienda a traerme esto", "Córrele, ves a verlo (al señor).

Answer (score 2):

" Ves" se dice mucho en Valencia, cuando hablamos español, porque en valenciano, en imperativo del verbo IR (Anar) es VES.